# Possible to use overflow:hidden to crop img as square but keep the ratio in percentage-based-width container?

Tags: css, image

I'm pulling images that are all different sizes but want them to be squares inside a grid made of inline-block list items that are percentage-based-width. The page I'm building is: http://ohmydrifter.com/category/inspiration/ and my HTML is:

```
<ul id="inspiration-grid">

     <li class="mix">

            <div class="grid-thumbnail">    
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            </div><!-- end grid-thumbnail -->    

            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

    </li> <!-- .mix -->

</ul> <!-- end #inspiration-grid -->
```

My CSS is:

```
.grid-thumbnail {
overflow: hidden;
width: 184px;
height: 184px;
}
```

It works, but what I want to do is have the .grid-thumbnail divs be a percentage width. Is that possible to do while keeping the image cropped as squares?

Comment: Check also `background-size: cover` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a small trick since `padding` and `margin` are based on the element's width.

We set the `width` to whatever percentage we want. Then we set the`height` to `0`. Lastly we use `padding-bottom` to set how tall our container will be. Since padding is based on the width of the element, we make it the exact same value we used for `width`.

My example uses 20% as the percentage size.

```
.grid-thumbnail {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
}
```

Live example here: http://codepen.io/marceloa/pen/ojqayO

Comment: In your specific layout, you would use `100%` as the `width` and `padding-bottom`.